# How to resolve 'element not interactable' in selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

I hope to utilize <sub>selenium</sub> to interact with the [website](http://wordvec.colorado.edu/matrix_comparison.html). According to the logic of source, until I specify an item in a drop-down menu can I go on to the rest drop-down menus. However, the rest menus are still not interactable after specifying the first item. The rest elements are neither displayed nor interacted, even though set <sub>display="block"</sub>. How to resolve this issue?

My code is as follows:

```
import selenium.webdriver as wbd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time

driver = wbd.Chrome() # may alter with browser
driver.get('http://wordvec.colorado.edu/matrix_comparison.html') # fixed

vector_type = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'vector_type')
Select(vector_type).select_by_value("LSA")
time.sleep(1)

topic_space = driver.find_element(By.ID, "topic_space")
print(topic_space.is_displayed())
topic_space.send_keys("tasa") # fixed
time.sleep(1)

comparison_type = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'comparison_type')
comparison_type.send_keys('document') # fixed
time.sleep(1)

num_factors = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'num_factors')
num_factors.send_keys(str(30)) # set # or 100
time.sleep(1)
```

And the error is:

Message: element not interactable
(Session info: chrome=119.0.6045.105)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the below line:

```
topic_space = driver.find_element(By.ID, "topic_space")
```

If you notice the HTML, there are 3 elements with `ID=topic_space`. The desired element in your case is the third element. You can use following XPATH expression to locate the third element - `(//select[@id='topic_space'])[3]`.

So, change that line of code as below:

```
topic_space = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//select[@id='topic_space'])[3]")
```

**UPDATE:** In addition to above, your code had few more issues. Like the following code is not the right way - `topic_space.send_keys("tasa")` to select a dropdown value. It should be: `Select(topic_space).select_by_value("tasa")`. I have fixed such issues and also I have refactored your code by removing `time.sleep()` and have applied Selenium's [Waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/) instead, which are more effective.

**Check the below refactored code:**

```
import selenium.webdriver as wbd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = wbd.Chrome() # may alter with browser
driver.get('http://wordvec.colorado.edu/matrix_comparison.html') # fixed
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

vector_type = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "vector_type")))
Select(vector_type).select_by_value("LSA")

topic_space = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//select[@id='topic_space'])[3]")))
print(topic_space.is_displayed())
Select(topic_space).select_by_value("tasa")

comparison_type = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'comparison_type')))
Select(comparison_type).select_by_value("document")

num_factors = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "num_factors")))
num_factors.send_keys(str(30)) # set # or 100
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thx a lot! It works!